# Starting multiple files through batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, file-io, cmd

I am trying to write a batch file which when invoked through cmd would launch 3 programs consecutively. Here is what I have so far:

```
cd C:\Program Files\CPUID\CPU-Z\
cpuz.exe
cd "C:\Program Files\Core Temp\"
"Core Temp.exe"
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\EVGA Precision X\"
EVGAPrecision.exe
```

The problem is that when I execute this batch file it launches the first program and then simply pauses. Only when I close the first program does it go on to the second command. Keep in mind that each of these programs require permission from the user to run through the "Do you want to allow the following program to make changes to your computer?" thing.

The ideal scenario is to have all program launch at the same time with out prompting for permission, but if that is impossible, I'm fine with clicking "Yes" for each one of them as long as they still launch consecutively and I don't have to close each program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what your looking for:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\CPUID\CPU-Z\cpuz.exe"
start "" "C:\Program Files\Core Temp\Core Temp.exe"
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\EVGA Precision X\EVGAPrecision.exe"
```

Comment: You need to surround paths with spaces in them with double quotes (remember to add a blank for the title).